# Growth rate of power series coefficients for function holomorphic on a strip

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series

Suppose $f$ is holomorphic on the strip $\{ z \in \mathbb{C}: |\text{Im} \, z| < \delta \}$.  Consider the expansion $f(z) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k z^k$.  Is there a bound on the growth rate of the coefficients $a_k$?  In particular, I would like to know if there exist positive constants $M$ and $b$ such that
$$
|a_k| \leq M b^k,
$$
where $M$ and $b$ are allowed to depend on $f$.  (I had a spurious $k!$ on the RHS the first time I posted; I was thinking about both $f^{(k)}(0)$ and $a_k$ at the same time.)

Comment: Keywords: Cauchy, Hadamard.

Comment: I assume $M,b$ are allowed to depend on $f$?

Comment: Yes, that is right.

Comment: Well the radius of convergence is at least $\delta$ and there is a formula that gives the radius of convergence in terms of the $a_k.$

Comment: Yes, of course!  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just realized this question is trivial.  The terms of the power series must go to zero, so for $|z| < \delta$ there exists $M > 0$ such that $|a_k z^k| \leq M$.  We apply this at $z = \epsilon \delta$ for any $\epsilon \in (0,1)$ and we obtain $b = (\epsilon \delta)^{-1}$.  Done.